# AWS Cognito login with Google does not save user into user pools

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-cognito, google-signin

I don't know why AWS Cognito does not work when I use social media login, i.e. Google provider. I have set all required rules in `amplify` configuration, enable Google provider, and setup `awsconfiguration.json` as well. When I login using email or username, which is regular login using password, everything is ok. Users are saved into user pools:

[image: Normal sign in]

But when I login using Google, no user is saved. It seems that login information is saved to `SharedPreferences` only, and not to the cloud. Here's the proof:

[image: Google login]

I don't know why. Here's my code to login:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
        RESPONSE_SUCCESS_GOOGLE_LOGIN -> {
            try {
                val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
                AWSMobileClient.getInstance().federatedSignIn(IdentityProvider.GOOGLE.toString(), account.idToken, object : Callback<UserStateDetails> {
                    override fun onResult(details: UserStateDetails) {
                        // onResult is called, but the user information not saved to the cloud
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Exception) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "sign-in error", e)
                    }
                })
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can test a random string that is not a correct JWT token at all:

```
val randomJwt = "239rwienaffe"
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().federatedSignIn(IdentityProvider.GOOGLE.toString(), randomJwt, object : Callback<UserStateDetails> {
```

Then `onResult` is called and inform that login is success. Pretty funny, isn't? I don't know how to implement Google login with AWS Cognito correctly. It's extremely difficult to learn AWS than Firebase.

Do you have representation or steps to login with Google provider correctly? Do I need to implement something complex to achieve this simple feature? E.g. using combination between API Gateway, Lambda, IAM, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The code suggests that you are using [Cognito Identity Pool/Federated Identities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html) for Google sign in.
From [Amplify docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#federated-sign-in), The federatedSignIn() is used to get AWS credentials directly from Cognito Federated Identities, which is different from Cognito User Pools. In order to save the users who sign in via google, you need to [integrate Social login with Congito userpool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social-idp.html).

You may need to use Cognito hosted UI to integrate social login with userpool for your amplify app as per [this issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1143).